# How can I solve /bin/sh: python: command not found on Mac?

Tags: python-3.x

I already installed VS CODE on my Mac and did all the settings. I put codes in it, and it responded, "/bin/sh: python: command not found."

I tried all kinds of methods, but they didn't seem to help.

Here is a screenshot of the error.
Please help me.

Answer (score 2):

If you've python3 installed on your system, you can add a symbolic link to python3 with this command line

```
sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python3 /usr/local/bin/python
```

It'll use python3 as python.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the path of the python interpreter is misconfigured.
You can open a terminal and write the following command: `$ whereis python`

If this command does not return anything, it is likely that python is not installed (or undefined in the var env 'path') on your Mac.

If you have a path to an interpreter, change the interpreter path used by vscode.
Go to the settings and edit the field : "python : interpreter path" with the right one.

Good day.